# how do i pass value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a drop down where I want to pass the selected value I selected to the controller. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test(Test input)
    {
        string selected = input.YourDropDown; //Here is your value

        return View();
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public string YourDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<###NAMESPACE###.Models.Test>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
            <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YourDropDown, new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "Test", Value = "Value" }}) %>
            <input type="submit" />
        <% } %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Put the view in the folder like:
`/Views/Test/Test.aspx`

and your url will be:

`url/Test/Test`

This would properly be one of the better and most extensible ways to do what you what. You could avoid to make the model class and use `Html.DropDownList` instead of `Html.DropDownListFor`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass via the querystring like so:

http://YourMvcApp/YourController/YourAction/?yourvariable=yourvalue

Then inside your Action you can get to the value by doing

```
Dim myValue As Object = Request("yourvariable")
```

Or in C#

```
Object myValue = Request["yourvariable"];
```

HTH,

Mike